# Winforms control spacing in Windows 7

Tags: winforms, windows-7, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

We have an in-house .net 2.0 winforms app currently developed on Visual Studio 2005 in Windows XP. Everyone in the office until now is running Windows XP, and there are no issues.

We recently ordered a new computer with Windows 7 for one of our managers we were hoping to use, and the app installs fine.  The issue is the spacing around every label, textbox, and button - making some forms not fit.

Is there some setting that we can use to make Windows 7 display each control where it is placed in our XP development environment and like the rest of our XP clients show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, what kind of idiot management team gives a new machine to a *manager* instead of a programmer?

Control Panel + Display, Advanced tab, change the DPI setting to repro the problem on your XP machine.  Read the docs for the Form.AutoScaleMode to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for leading me in the right direction.  I can quick-fix this by forcing the Windows 7 machine to 100% (smaller) size in the Display options, rather than the 125% it defaults to. I'll still need to go back and fix this code-side, when we start rolling out more Windows 7 machines.

Comment: The manager got an oversize screen to go with the shiny new machine, eh? Windows 7 defaults your DPI based on screen size - XP is 100% unless you deliberately change it.